# Getting NSFetchedResultsController, NSSortDescription and sectionNameForKeyPath to work together

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm currently working on an App that has a couple of Entities and relationships as illustrated below:

**Item** <<--> **Category**.

I am currently fetching **Item** instances and displaying them in sections using the item's `category.name`. In this case I can use a sort descriptor to sort the categories by name, which is pretty straightforward and working fine (relevant code below):

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil)
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [order_ managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category.name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                          initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:moc
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"category.name"
                                          cacheName:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = controller;
    [controller release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
        // Error handling
    }
    return fetchedResultsController_;
}
```

My problem now is that I need to sort these categories not by name, but by a `(NSNumber*) displayOrder` attribute that is part of the **Category** entity. **BUT** I need the section titles on the tableview to continue to use the categorie's `name`.

If I set the sortDescriptor to use `category.displayOrder` and keep the sectionNameKeyPath as `category.name`, the section titles work fine but the sortDescriptor is simply ignored by the fetchedResultsController and the table sections are ordered by the category's name (not sure why??).

My next idea was to overwrite the `displayOrder` getter method but that didn't get me too far as the return types are different, plus I needed the actual displayOrder value for the section sorting.

So right now I have a solution which feels a bit clunky (code below), and I am wondering if there is a better way of achieving the same thing using the fetchedResultsController alone.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
// The code below grabs a reference to first object for a given section
// and uses it to return the associated category name
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *menuItems = [sectionInfo objects];
    if ([menuItems count] > 0)
    {
        MenuItem *menuItem = [menuItems objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *categoryName = menuItem.category.name;
        return categoryName;
    }
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

Am I missing something basic here?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Rog

Comment: Did you look at Apple's The Elements example project? As I recall, it deals with all this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a perfectly good solution to the problem, Rog.

You certainly don't want/need to subclass NSFetchedResultsController.

@aroth, we don't have enough information to know the details of his object model, but the names certainly imply that category **does not own** item.  Item has a category.  His intent is to display a list of items, that is why he is fetching items.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in coming back to this. In the end I went with my initial solution and it seems to be working fine for what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: 'Own' may not have been the best term, but if each `Item` has a `Category`, then each `Category` has a collection of `Items`.  And his intent is to display a list of items, *grouped into sections and ordered by category*.  So it doesn't make sense to fetch items and then try to manually group and order them when you could fetch a sorted list of categories and simply use `[category items]` to get all the items belonging to each category.  Done in iterative fashion that will build the desired list of items in the correct order, with no custom sorting/grouping required.

Answer (score 1):

As far as sorting goes, [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/initWithFetchRequest%3amanagedObjectContext%3asectionNameKeyPath%3acacheName%3a) has this to say:

> If the controller generates sections, the first sort descriptor in the array is used to group the objects into sections; its key must either be the same as sectionNameKeyPath or the relative ordering using its key must match that using sectionNameKeyPath.

In English (you may already know this Rog, but then again you may not and certainly people who search this later may appreciate the explanation), that means if you're using sections then the sorting on the NSFetchRequest must group all items in the same section together. This could be by making the first sort criteria be the field used as the section name, or it could be by making the first sort criteria be something else that results in the same sort of grouping.

The documentation doesn't specify what happens if you screw this up; it's possible it would just totally screw up the section names, repeat sections, skip sections, detect the situation and "fix" your sorting, or even just crash. Do any of your categories have the same displayOrder?

Your solution is certainly workable, and if you can't get it to work correctly sorting by displayOrder while titling sections by category.name it's probably your best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you fetching `Item` and not `Category`?  If I understand your relationships correctly, `Category` owns a 1 to many relationship with `Item`, so in theory a `Category` instance should have an 'items' property that returns every `Item` in that category.

If that's the case, then you could simply fetch all of your categories, and then sort them by `displayOrder`.  Then, forget about using sections in the `NSFetchedResultsController` itself.  Instead, your associated `tableView` methods would look something like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    Category* category = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[category items] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    Category* category = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:section];
    return category.name;
}
```

In short, I think you are overcomplicating things by fetching `Item` instead of `Category`, and by trying to make the `NSFetchedResultsController` manage your section grouping for you.  It is much simpler and requires much less code to just do the section management yourself.

Comment: I have a similar problem and was reading your solution. What would you do if Item has a displayOrder as well? Category.items is a NSSet, how would you order the Items by displayOrder?

Comment: @Zyphrax - I would call `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` on the `NSSet` to get a consistently ordered list, if that's what was required.  As discussed in the [reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. What would be the right time to call `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`? How would that work together with a `UITableView`? And wouldn't new items found by the FetchedRC disturb the order?

Comment: @Zyphrax - You'd call it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and also in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` if you implement that method.  Basically anywhere where you want to know which `Item` corresponds to a particular location in the table.  New items are a problem that needs to be handled regardless of how the data actually makes it into the table.  They do impact the order, yes, so it's important to update/reload the affected section(s) whenever the dataset changes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to subclass NSFetchedResultsController and customize the section name functions. See the NSFetchedResultsController class docs on subclassing.

Comment: You create a subclass of this class if you want to customize the creation of sections and index titles. You override sectionIndexTitleForSectionName: if you want the section index title to be something other than the capitalized first letter of the section name. You override sectionIndexTitles if you want the index titles to be something other than the array created by calling sectionIndexTitleForSectionName: on all the known sections.