# NSFetchedResultsController - how does sectionNameForKeypath get its data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I've been having a few nightmares with NSFetchedResultsController and in trying to find a solution to my problem outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367419/getting-nsfetchedresultscontroller-nssortdescription-and-sectionnameforkeypath-t), I came across something unusual about the data being fetched by a fetchedResultsController, particularly the `sectionNameForKeypath` parameter.

Suppose I have an object model with 2 Entities and relationships as per below:

**Item** <<--> **Category**

Category has an (NSNumber*) attribute called `displayOrder` which is used to separate the fetched **Item** instances into sections in a table view:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                          initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:moc
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"category.displayOrder"
                                          cacheName:nil];
```

If I wanted to somehow manipulate the output of `displayOrder` dynamically, the obvious choice would be to overwrite its getter method and do whatever I want in there. But the problem is, the getter for `displayOrder` is never accessed during the fetchRequest or by the fetchedResultsController at all, even though I am specifying it in the `sectionNameForKeypath`, AND I can see the fetchedResultsController is using its values to separate and display the sections.

Here's a simple example of an overwritten getter method which never gets called. This was placed inside my Category class:

```
-(NSNumber*)displayOrder
{
    NSLog (@"displayOrder getter called");
    NSNumber *displayOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    return displayOrder;
}
```

I've also tried overwriting `awakeFromFetch` to no avail (also doesn't get called, but that doesn't surprise me as I'm fetching Item instances and accessing the category and its attributes through the relationships).

So finally my question is: how does the `category.displayOrder` values get passed to my fetchedResultsController and is there a way for me to control this output?

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have!

Rog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 3.2, NSFetchedResultsController uses the field identified by sectionNameKeyPath directly from the database whenever possible, rather than creating objects for every item. You could try using a non-persistent property for the sectionNameKeyPath, which (according to the documentation) would force it to create the objects, but if it's just a matter of renaming the sections for a UITableView it would be better to do the mapping in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Anomie! Do you have a link to where in the docs this is discussed? Cheers!

Comment: [Here you go](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW33)